# Replacing Terms of a Table of Functions

Tags: warning-messages, splines, table

I define a table of functions, and I receive and error when I want to change a term of the table. As a minimal example, I can give the following.

```
f[t_]=Table[t,{k,1,10}];
f[t_][[2]]=Integrate[f[s][[1]],{s,0,t}]
```

Here is the warning message I receive.

```
Set::setps: f[t_] in the part assignment is not a symbol.
```

How to get rid of this problem?

My main idea is to use a recursive formula to construct a matrix of piecewisely defined functions such as the B-Spline

**Note**. The example is updated due to Nasser's comment.

Comment: There is no `t` in the RHS. So how is `f` a function of `t`?

Comment: Maybe you should try to describe in words what you're trying to do. Your code makes no sense, and so we would just be speculating.

Comment: Perhaps you want `f = Table[1, {k, 1, 10}]; f[[2]] = t; f`

Comment: @lericr I want to define B-Spline functions.

Comment: @Nasser My iteration would start with a constant function and then I will build my iterations. Okay, just updated my example.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you would define BSplines by recursion. The first examples assumes, for simplicity, knots at 0,1,2..

```
ClearAll[b];
b[i_, 0][x_] := If[i <= x < i + 1, 1, 0];
b[i_, j_][
  x_] := (x - i)/j  b[i, j - 1][x] + (i + j + 1 - x)/
    j    b[i + 1, j - 1][x]
b[1, 0][x]
Table[Plot[b[i, j][x], {x, -1, 4}, PlotRange -> All], {j, 0, 2}, {i, 
   0, 2}] // Grid
```

[image]

If you have arbitrary knots, given in an array: kn, then it is a bit more complicated. (Note "i" as an index starts at 1 not a 0):

```
ClearAll[b];
kn = Range[0, 10];
b[i_, 0][x_] := If[kn[[i]] <= x < kn[[i + 1]], 1, 0];
b[i_, j_][
  x_] := (x - kn[[i]])/(kn[[i + j]] - kn[[i]])  b[i, j - 1][
    x] + (kn[[i + j + 1]] - x)/(kn[[i + j + 1]] - kn[[i + 1]]) b[
     i + 1, j - 1][x]

Table[Plot[b[i, j][x], {x, -1, 5}, PlotRange -> All], {j, 0, 2}, {i, 
   3}] // Grid
```

[image]

Comment: So, I am allowed to use indices but not tables as functions for manipulations...

Comment: No, the problem with your attempt is that "Set" has the attribute "HoldFirst". Therefore, the left side of your assignment is not evaluated.

Comment: I did *not* know that we do *not* need **For** loop for iterating recursive functions.

Comment: You may define a recursion by defining a function that calls itself.